# How to configure proxy CA certificate in browser?

Tags: firefox, burp-suite

I was trying to download burp's CA certificate for Firefox on Kali from http://burp as specified in its documentation but the site is not available. It redirects me to http://www.inert.com/. So is there any alternative to download the certificate?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you are using BURP as your proxy in your browser first.  It sounds like you aren't doing that.

From their docs:

> If you have not already done so, configure your browser to use Burp as its proxy, and configure Burp's Proxy listener to generate CA-signed per-host certificates (this is the default setting).

https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/1783087-Installing_Installing%20CA%20Certificate%20-%20FF.html